# Is there a way to shorten a process with the help of a for loop in a two stock variance formula?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I am new to VBA and I need someone to help me with the for loop because my program is becoming too repetitive. I have written a code that will calculate the variance of two stocks. The code seems to be working fine. I just need a **for loop** for the last part of the code where the formula will be calculated and executed. Range M15 to M25 contains percentages from 0 to 100 and Range N15 to N25 contains percentages from 100 to 0 and sometimes this code doesn't work in non English computers.

This is my code below. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
    Dim var1 As String
    Dim var2 As String
    Dim covarval As String
    Dim covar1 As Range
    Dim covar2 As Range

    If ComboBox1 = "Royal Dutch Shell" Then var1 = Range("B35")
    If ComboBox1 = "Exxon Mobil Corp" Then var1 = Range("C35")
    If ComboBox2 = "Biogen Inc" Then var2 = Range("F35")
    If ComboBox2 = "Johnson & Johnson" Then var2 = Range("G35")

    If ComboBox1 = "Royal Dutch Shell" Then
    Set covar1 = Range("rds")

    ElseIf ComboBox1 = "Exxon Mobil Corp" Then
    Set covar1 = Range("exon")
End If
    If ComboBox2 = "Biogen Inc" Then
    Set covar2 = Range("bign")

    ElseIf ComboBox2 = "Johnson & Johnson" Then
    Set covar2 = Range("jhnsn")
End If

Range("B39").Formula = "=COVAR(" & covar1.Address & "," & covar2.Address & ")"
covarval = Range("B39").Value

Sheets("EfficientFrontier").Select

   "I need **for loop** for this part"

Range("p15").Formula = "=M15^2*" & var1 & "+N15^2*" & var2 & "+2*M15*N15* " & covarval & ""
Range("p16").Formula = "=M16^2*" & var1 & "+N16^2*" & var2 & "+2*M16*N16* " & covarval & ""
Range("p17").Formula = "=M17^2*" & var1 & "+N17^2*" & var2 & "+2*M17*N17* " & covarval & ""
Range("p18").Formula = "=M18^2*" & var1 & "+N18^2*" & var2 & "+2*M18*N18* " & covarval & ""
Range("p19").Formula = "=M19^2*" & var1 & "+N19^2*" & var2 & "+2*M19*N19* " & covarval & ""
Range("p20").Formula = "=M20^2*" & var1 & "+N20^2*" & var2 & "+2*M20*N20* " & covarval & ""
Range("p21").Formula = "=M21^2*" & var1 & "+N21^2*" & var2 & "+2*M21*N21* " & covarval & ""
Range("p22").Formula = "=M22^2*" & var1 & "+N22^2*" & var2 & "+2*M22*N22* " & covarval & ""
Range("p23").Formula = "=M23^2*" & var1 & "+N23^2*" & var2 & "+2*M23*N23* " & covarval & ""
Range("p24").Formula = "=M24^2*" & var1 & "+N24^2*" & var2 & "+2*M24*N24* " & covarval & ""
Range("p25").Formula = "=M25^2*" & var1 & "+N25^2*" & var2 & "+2*M25*N25* " & covarval & ""
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the last part of your code, the variable part of each line is a number which goes from 15 to 25.  Therefore, a For loop like this can reduce your lines of code:

```
For i = 15 To 25
   Range("P" & i).Formula = "=M" & i & "^2*" & var1 & "+N" & i & "^2*" & var2 & "+2*M" & i & "*N" & i & "* " & covarval & ""
Next
```

As you can see, the numbers have been replaced with `i` which goes from 15 to 25.